Unable to preventing the Popover from closing when interacting outside of it in nextui
I am Nextui with Next.js I want to prevent the Popover from closing when interacting outside of it.  I have used the shouldCloseOnInteractOutside prop as per the documentation but it's not able to prevent the Popover(NextUI) from closing when interacting outside of popover. Setting the prop isKeyboardDismissDisabled to true is making sure that I can't use the esc key to close the popover, however when I click outside the popover, it's closing.
<Popover
    isOpen={isOpen}
    onOpenChange={setIsOpen}
    classNames={{ content: 'p-0' }}
    placement="top"
    offset={15}
    backdrop="blur"
    isDismissable={false}
    isKeyboardDismissDisabled={true}
    shouldCloseOnInteractOutside={() => false} >

How do i make sure that the popover does not close when I click outside of it. Thanks in advance.

not a perfect solution but adding a max height to PopoverContent and making it scrollable solves the issue:
  <PopoverContent className="max-h-[yourHeight] overflow-y-auto">
           <div/>
  </PopoverContent>

